# Can not boot anything other then windows 10 from any source. Windows boot manager redirects boot to the c: drive every time

Tags: boot

I want to completely remove windows from the computer and install linux. I have downloaded the linux boot program onto a flash drive and changed the bios boot sequence to the external source, changed the priority to move the source to 1., disabled secure boot. Windows boot manager reinserts itself in position 1. every time I try. I have looked at bcdedit and tried to delete the boot manager string, but it will not let me. How do I get past this so the linux program can install? I do not want a dual boot system.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to what *Linux* you're asking about, but most Ubuntu products will boot & install if booted in *legacy*, uEFI or Secure-uEFI mode so you shouldn't need to disable secure-boot if you wrote the ISO to media correctly (*ie. didnt' just copy it there as a data file; it needs to be burnt or written as bootable media correctly for your unstated product/release*).

Comment: Turn OFF Windows' "Fast Boot" or "Fast Startup" setting. Then, your BIOS should let you change the boot order and boot from the USB stick.

Comment: How you boot external media is device specific, and one some of my devices it's a *royal pain*...  eg. On one that's *from from the worst* I need to hold down a key whilst the device is off & it'll turn on and ask if I want to boot external media (*if it's on already it won't boot external*), on others it requires me to change/select it in uEFI setup each time.... ie. your device *firmware* will control how you do it on your device, the OS being booted is irrelevant (*as long as you wrote it correctly so the media is bootable; it'll be ignored otherwise*).